# Is there a C header parser tool for wrapper generation like gccxml?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, parsing, wrapper

I need to write a few c header wrappers for a new programming language and would like something like gccxml but without the full dependency on gcc and the problems it gives on a windows system.

Just needs to read C not C++. Output in any format is okay as long it is fully documented.

Need it for Curl, SQLite, GTK2, SDL, OpenGL, Win32 API and C posix API's on Linux/Solaris/FreeBSD/MacOSX.

Comment: Try to use [ABI Compliance Checker](http://ispras.linuxbase.org/index.php/ABI_compliance_checker#Usage_as_a_Parser_of_API) tool as a parser of C header files. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12546962/241776) for instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VivaCore](http://www.viva64.com/vivacore-library/) is very cool. Have you tried [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) the wikipedia page on [ffi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) has some good links too.  I think there is a MSVC codedom example that does C also.

Answer (score 1):

See our [SD C Front End for DMS](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html).  Full C parsing, symbol table construction, post parsing dump of any information you like.  Can dump code and symbol tables in XML format.

Comment: Wow, haven't seen this answer I gave since I wrote it 4 years ago.  Added standard SO indication of self-interest, *our*, that was not a requirement when I first gave this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may like [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) in Python. Used in [CFFI](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and other awesome projects.