# C++ Unit Testing: Stubs (not mocks)?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, stub, googlemock

Just getting into Unit Testing with C++.  It looks like I will need to write several stub classes as I go along.  My understanding is there is a difference between Mocks and Stubs.  Basically it seems Mocks are for when you are testing something happened on the object (e.g. verifying) while Stubs just facilitate your test.  I guess for mocking, I can use googlemock but I don't see anything in it for creating Stubs (ala RhinoMocks' GenerateStub).

Is there a way to get automatically generated stubs? Does googlemock have any support for stubs?  Or do I pretty much have to manually create stubs for testing?

Comment: Not sure but I hear boost has a unit test library. Unfortunately I have to concede with aloneguid I have never written code for unit testing.

Comment: Isn't there some sort of generator python script which can generate some mock classes?

Comment: @aloneguid: Seriously? I don't believe that. Real C++ people use whatever tests are appropriate for their application.

Comment: @Nim: There's no reason to do that when everything is possible in plain C++.

Comment: @Billy, of course, I guess it's for the really lazy! ;)

Comment: @Nim: I believe you are correct googlemock has a generator script, gmock_gen.py, which will take a c++ class file and attempt to print out the mock class definition for you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the missing piece of the puzzle is that you don't have to set an expectation on a method and instead you can just set a default return value.

**Mocks**

All the discussion and examples in the "[Google Mock for Dummies](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md)" is focused around setting expectations.  Everything talks about using some code similar to the following:

```
EXPECT_CALL(turtle, PenDown())
      .Times(AtLeast(1));
```

Which is what you want for mocking, but for stubbing you don't have any expectations.  After reading that intro I had no clue how to use googlemock for stubbing.

**Stubs**

ratkok's comment led me to find out how to set a default return value.  Here's how to specify a return value for a mocked object but no expectation:

```
ON_CALL(foo, Sign(_))
      .WillByDefault(Return(-1));
```

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#setting-the-default-actions-for-a-mock-method

It appears googlemock will issue a warning if you call a method that has no EXPECT_CALL.  Apparently you can prevent this warning by using their [NiceMock](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#the-nice-the-strict-and-the-naggy-nicestrictnaggy) construct or you can just ignore it.  Additionally it appears you can avoid the warning by using an expect instead (which I'm not sure if it's a good idea for stubs). From the [Google Mock FAQ](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#uninteresting-calls):

```
EXPECT_CALL(foo, Bar(_))
    .WillRepeatedly(...);
```

I believe that is exactly what I was trying to figure out.

**Update**

I can confirm this works.  I wrote a unit test using google test along with googlemock and was able to stub out a method for a class using ON_CALL.

Comment: Yes, using ON_CALL() and NiceMock is exactly what I was referring too. Check those wiki pages (google mock) - this mocking framework is really quite powerful and flexible.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference between a Mock and a Stub is that a Mock enforces behavior, while a Stub does not.

As far as I am aware, Google Mock's mocks are actually stubs by default. They only enforce behavior if you place assertions on the various methods.

Comment: I guess what I'm confused about is I want to define a stub behavior.  For example a method IsValidUser() that will return true.  I don't want to create an expecation on IsValidUser because I want to test something else and IsValidUser is merely a dependency to test another method.  But everything in googlemocks seems to be oriented around creating an expectation

Comment: You can avoid setting expectations in google mock by providing default values/behavior. Also, google mock framework let you ignore unexpected calls so your tests will not fail if the expectation does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [stubgen](http://www.radwin.org/michael/projects/stubgen/) and the similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020568/seeking-code-stub-generator-from-header-files).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236086/parsing-c-to-generate-unit-test-stubs) maybe useful/related as well.

Regarding google mocks - we use it on my current project to fully automate stub implementation. Virtually the entire stub code base is implemented using google mocks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/coolxv/cpp-stub

```
//for linux and windows
#include<iostream>
#include "stub.h"
using namespace std;
int foo(int a)
{   
    cout<<"I am foo"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
int foo_stub(int a)
{   
    cout<<"I am foo_stub"<<endl;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    Stub stub;
    stub.set(foo, foo_stub);
    foo(1);
    return 0;
}
```